# Getting OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool tunnel error while installing python packages in windows 10

Tags: proxy

```
C:\Users\BSTC>pip install mkdocs
Collecting mkdocs
  Obtaining dependency information for mkdocs from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/89/58/aa3301b23966a71d7f8e55233f467b3cec94a651434e9cd9053811342539/mkdocs-1.5.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1000)'))': /packages/89/58/aa3301b23966a71d7f8e55233f467b3cec94a651434e9cd9053811342539/mkdocs-1.5.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1000)'))': /packages/89/58/aa3301b23966a71d7f8e55233f467b3cec94a651434e9cd9053811342539/mkdocs-1.5.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1000)'))': /packages/89/58/aa3301b23966a71d7f8e55233f467b3cec94a651434e9cd9053811342539/mkdocs-1.5.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1000)'))': /packages/89/58/aa3301b23966a71d7f8e55233f467b3cec94a651434e9cd9053811342539/mkdocs-1.5.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1000)'))': /packages/89/58/aa3301b23966a71d7f8e55233f467b3cec94a651434e9cd9053811342539/mkdocs-1.5.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/89/58/aa3301b23966a71d7f8e55233f467b3cec94a651434e9cd9053811342539/mkdocs-1.5.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1000)')))


[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.2.1 -> 23.3.1
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

I have tried in stalling pip package:

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip install mkdocs
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOwKM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org mkdocs
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?